# Is there any alternative service like in Amazon Appstream2.0 and Amazon Workspace in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to search for an alternative of Amazon Appstream2.0 and Amazon Workspace(DAAS) in GCP. Those services in Amazon really provide the solution for remote purpose but I am really handy with azure. If I can get the solution in GCP I can move to GCP for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud for AWS Professionals](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/):

> This guide is designed to equip professionals who are familiar with
> Amazon Web Services (AWS) with the key concepts required to get
> started with Google Cloud. The guide compares Google Cloud with AWS
> and highlights the similarities and differences between the two. In
> addition, the guide provides quick-reference mappings of AWS products,
> concepts, and terminology to the corresponding products, concepts, and
> terminology on Google Cloud.

---

> [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) is a managed, secure Desktop-as-a-Service (DaaS)
> solution. You can use Amazon WorkSpaces to provision either Windows or
> Linux desktops in just a few minutes and quickly scale to provide
> thousands of desktops to workers across the globe.

There is no similar GCP product, but you can use [variety of 3rd party products](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/virtual-desktops) to configure Desktop-as-a-Service:

1. [itopia](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/partners/itopia-public?_ga=2.234354718.1090047675.1598377254-1698584973.1584367323&_gac=1.250285746.1598445464.EAIaIQobChMIx-XAqfG46wIV2ON3Ch2UXwCbEAAYASAAEgJOvPD_BwE)
2. [Citrix Virtual Apps and Desktops](https://www.citrix.com/global-partners/google/citrix-workspace-google-cloud.html)
3. [Nutanix Frame](https://www.nutanix.com/products/frame/google)
4. VMware Horizon on [Google Cloud VMware Engine](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine)
5. [Workspot](https://www.workspot.com/)

---

> Amazon AppStream 2.0 is a fully managed non-persistent application and
> desktop streaming service. You centrally manage your desktop
> applications on AppStream 2.0 and securely deliver them to any
> computer.

There is no specific GCP product that performs the same tasks as Amazon AppStream, but you could accomplish the same result with multiple GCP or 3rd party products like [Citrix Virtual Apps and Desktops](https://www.citrix.com/global-partners/google/citrix-workspace-google-cloud.html) or [Nutanix Frame](https://www.nutanix.com/products/frame/google).